# Is "thing" the most general in meaning

Tags: meaning, nouns, semantics

I'd like to know if *thing* is the most general in meaning among the nouns. In other words, is there an entity that can not be called as a thing? I know *being* refers to all the lives (animals and plants), *substance* can refer to all the  materials in the world, and *idea* refers to pieces of thought in the mind. But lives, substances and ideas can all be called things.

For example, if we want to find a word for all entities in the world with the white color, we can say the everything is white, or snow is white, where *white* is adjective and the object is known as a subject complement. But what is for noun? Can we say that snow is a white thing? Of course, we can say that snow is a white substance. In addition, we can say a polar bear is white or a polar bear is a white being. But can we say a polar bear is a white thing?

Generally, this relies on whether a subject complement can always be replaced by a noun (phrase). If so, *thing* is (probably) the best candidate of noun to be used.

Comment: "Thing" refers to anything.  (Or to a [hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing_(The_Addams_Family)) in The Addams Family.)

Comment: Everything is a thing.

Comment: The comments above tell me that your question is inadequately posed. You really need to give us more to go on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there anything that cannot be called a thing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/422054), which, however, does not have a satisfactory answer. Is this a question about how to use these words in everyday contexts, or an invitation to a philosophical discussion?

Comment: There's no reason that you couldn't give a list of "white things" and list snow, polar bears, and milk.

Comment: @jsw29, yes, the post is close to what I want to know, but with wrong title. It should be "Is there some entities that can not be called a thing or things?". This question is part of my research on semantics. It looks like *thing* is the broadest concept as far as I know. It covers everything in the physical world as well as in the mind. For example, we can say "think of things". So a mental object or concept can also be called a thing.

Comment: Oh, ontology. Well, you could start with [Frawley's properties of entities](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/frawleyentities.pdf) (which usually turn out to be nouns)

Comment: The elementary school definition of noun is a person, place, or thing. Which leads one to assume that persons and places aren’t things.

Comment: "In other words, is there an *entity* that can not be called as a thing?" Could you also ask this about *entity*? The trouble with your question is that it is ontologically slippery. As soon as you start trying to describe any one word as "the most general," you end up invoking words that, if language were working strictly logically, would be at least as general as the original word. *Entity*, *being*, *item*, *substance* - there's an element of linguistic play and arbitrariness in saying any are "the most general." It's like asking if there is a "wettest noun."

Comment: I am not sure about any other word in place of *thing* and so I used *entity* which is the closest to *thing* in meaning. I feel that *thing* is the most general noun for it seems including any other noun in meaning, i.e. *life, being, substance* and *idea*. If you disagree, you can always refute it in another answer

Comment: Mass nouns often can't be called "thing", but they can be called "stuff"

Comment: @Spencer, I disagree with you. They can be called "things", i.e. stuff is also a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Thing, being, entity, substance* are all words that **can** be used as the terms for what there is, when  one doesn’t want to say anything about it other than that it is.

Generally, the first three imply that we are referring to something countable; *substance* is usually used for something uncountable. That, however, is not a strict rule. If I am asked whether there are any white things over there, it wouldn’t be wrong to respond ‘yes, there is some snow there’. On the other hand, *substance* was used as a countable term in earlier periods of the history of philosophy (and consequently may be so used in the present-day discussions of the works from that era).

The meaning of *substance*, incidentally, does not restrict it to material substance; it is possible to speak of spiritual substance or mental substance. One may, of course, claim that material substance is the only kind that there is, but that is a matter of one’s philosophical theory; the meaning of the word *substance* does not by itself rule out the other kinds.

Setting aside *substance*, it is largely a matter of preference and style whether to use *thing, being* or *entity*. The last one belongs to a more formal register, but is otherwise interchangeable with the other two.

In everyday English, *thing* is often understood to imply that we are speaking of something inanimate, but that is also not a strict rule. If I am asked whether there any white things over there, it would, again, be natural to include polar bears among the white things.

One should bear in mind that although these four terms are highly general, they are usually (but, again, not always) understood to stand in contrast to qualities, properties, characteristics, etc.: things **have** properties.

Comment: That is almost right:  not quite, however.  'Thing' can also stand for the full range of emotions.  So "I have a thing about going to the cinema" or "I have a thing for Jo(e)"....  You cannot have an entity or substance or item about either of these.  People can be said to "do their thing" but not their item, substance or entity.

Comment: @Tuffy, true, what has been said above does not cover the uses of *thing* in the idioms such as *to have a thing for* or *to do one's thing*; such special-purpose uses of the word seem to be outside the scope of what the OP was interested in.

Comment: Perhaps:  but it is relevant to the truth claim that it is the most general English word.